# Grid CSS свойства: grid-row-start: и grid-row-end:

Tags: css-grid

https://codepen.io/yasakova/pen/mdxvxpr

Объясните почему box1 находится вертикально в 1-3 строке, а не в 1-4 строке как указано:

```
  .box1 {
      grid-row-start: 1;
      grid-row-end: 4;
    }
```

Как исправить, не добавляя в элементы в html?

Comment: это не кол-во блоков

Comment: кажется поняла, 
Последняя 4 строка называется не "4", а "-1"
И нужно указать grid-row-end: - 1.
Тогда элемент будет находиться на 4 строке